# Kernel of a morphism of $k$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes, affine-varieties

Assume you have two affine varieties $X$ and $Y$. A morphism $\phi$ between them induces a morphism between the k-algebras of regular functions (functions on them that are locally the quotients of polynomials) $\phi^*:\mathcal{O}_Y(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Assuming $\phi^*$ is surjective, what can one say about its kernel?

It is obviously an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ but I was wondering if it has to be radical or even prime. I was wondering maybe there is an analogous of the nullstellensatz for this setting. Thanks to anyone who might have any tips.

Comment: If $X = Spec(A), Y = Spec(B)$ then the kernel of $\phi^* : B \to A$ is the preimage of $(0) \subset A$. If $A$ is integral, then the kernel is prime, hence radical.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Here $X$ and $Y$ are merely closed subsets of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ over an algebraically closed field. I am not yet familiar with higher notions of variety. To be precise they are couples $(X, O_X)$ consisting of closed subsets and sheaves of regular functions on them, regular meaning what I wrote in the post.

Comment: @Watson Can I say that since I know both $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ are reduced and $\phi^*$ is surjective, then $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong \mathcal{O}_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$ and thus that kernel has to be radical?

Comment: Yes, and for this you don't need surjectivity : $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$ is always a _subalgebra_ of $O_X(X)$, and a subring of a reduced ring is reduced. Finally, if $X$ is also irreducible, then $O_X(X)$ is an integral domain, so that $\ker(\phi^*)$ is prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need surjectivity of $\phi^*$ for this : $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$ is always a *subalgebra* of $O_X(X)$, and a subring of a reduced ring is reduced. [Thus](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Radical_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Reduced) $\ker(\phi^*)$ is a radical ideal of $O_Y(Y)$.

Finally, if $X$ is also irreducible, then $O_X(X)$ is an integral domain and so is $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$, so that $\ker(\phi^*)$ is prime.

Comment: Yes. Do you think it's also true that then $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)/\ker(\phi^*)$ is the a k-algebra corresponding to a closed subset of $Y$? A closed subvariety basically

Comment: @Dalamar : yes, a closed immersion $f' : Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ corresponds to a _surjective_ ring morphism $f : A \to B$. Here, $R := O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$ provides a surjective morphism $O_Y(Y) \to R$, so $Spec(R)$ is the closed subvariety $V(\ker(\phi^*)) \subset Y$. But the _injective_ morphism $R \to O_X(X)$ should rather correspond to a _dominant_ map, on the geometric side.

Comment: Why this correspondence surjective $\iff$ closed?

Comment: @Dalamar : exercise II.2.18 c), d) in Hartshorne.

Comment: Since we are here, would this also correspond to the morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ factoring as $\iota \circ \phi$ where $\iota$ is an inclusion and $\phi$ an isomorphism?

Comment: @Dalamar : I don't understand your comment. What is «this» referring to in your sentence "would this also correspond…". In general, $\phi$ is not assumed to be an isomorphism! And what is $f$?

Comment: Sorry, wrong notation. It all started from a morphism $\phi$ of affine varieties $X$ and $Y$. Since it induces a k-algebra homomorphism, we were able to have this algebraic discussion we just had. My question is: my book says on the geometric side this implies the morphism $\phi$ splits into an isomorphism $X \rightarrow Z(\ker(\phi^*))$ and an inclusion $\iota: Z(\ker(\phi^*)) \rightarrow Y$. I am not entirely sure I see why.

Comment: @Dalamar : on the algebraic side, this is just a surjection followed by an inclusion $$O_Y(Y) \to R := O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*) \to O_X(X).$$ Take $Spec( \cdot )$ of all this, you get $$X \to Spec(R) = Z(\ker(\phi^*)) \to Y.$$ We have $X \cong Spec(R)$ if $\phi^*$ is surjective (because then $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*) \cong O_X(X)$).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, about your first claim, that the quotient is a sub-algebra, are you sure you meant of $\mathcal{O}_X(X$) and not of the domain $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$?

Comment: @Dalamar : you have a morphism $O_Y(Y) \to O_X(X)$ whose image is isomorphic to $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$, so what I wrote should be right.

Comment: But the quotient $O_Y(Y) / \ker(\phi^*)$ consists basically equivalence classes of elements of $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ @Watson

Comment: @Dalamar : this quotient is _isomorphic_ to the image of $\phi^*$, which is a subalgebra of $O_X(X)$.

Comment: yes that's clear I was just wondering if one can say something about its structure without appealing to isomorphisms but it's ok :)